# XSD Schema not working as expected

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have created this xsd schema:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:simpleType name="stringtype">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="inttype">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger"/>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="dectype">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal"/>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:complexType name="RelativeText">
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="stringtype" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="flow" type="stringtype" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="amount" type="inttype"  use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="LineText">
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="stringtype" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="BoxText">
    <xs:attribute name="width" type="dectype" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="height" type="dectype" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="x" type="dectype" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="y" type="dectype" use="required" />
</xs:complexType> 
<xs:complexType name="templatecontenttype">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="line-text"        type="LineText" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="box-text"         type="BoxText"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
    <xs:element name="relative-text"    type="RelativeText" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="output-directory" type="stringtype" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="template-content" type="templatecontenttype"  />
</xs:schema>
```

And for this xml :

```
    <?xml version='1.0'?>  
  <template-content output-directory='D:\\output'>
<line-text name='a' />
<relative-text name='b' flow='above' amount='1'/>
<box-text name='c' x='1' y='2' width='2' height='2' />

</template-content>
```

And it says this:

Line: 5, Position: 2 "The element 'template-content' has invalid child element 'box-tex
t'. List of possible elements expected: 'relative-text'."

C# code:

```
 XmlWriterSettings ws = new XmlWriterSettings();
            ws.Indent = true;

            XmlReaderSettings rs = new XmlReaderSettings();
            rs.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            rs.ValidationEventHandler += new System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler(rs_ValidationEventHandler);
            rs.Schemas.Add(null, xsdFilePath);
            rs.CloseInput = true;

             rs.ValidationFlags =
                            XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings |
                            XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints |
                            XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema |
                            XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;

            StringReader r = new StringReader(xmlString);
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(r, rs))
            {

                // Parse the file and display each of the nodes.
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        switch (reader.NodeType)
                        {
                            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                                {

                                    if (reader.Name == "relative-text")
                                    {
                                        //Console.WriteLine("we found custom-text");
                                        //Console.WriteLine(reader["name"]);
                                        //Console.WriteLine(reader["flow"]);
                                        //Console.WriteLine(reader["amount"]);
                                    }
                                    else if (reader.Name == "line-text")
                                    {
                                       // Console.WriteLine(reader["names"]);
                                    }
                                    else if (reader.Name == "box-text")
                                    {
                                        //Console.WriteLine("x" + reader["x"]);
                                        //Console.WriteLine("y" + reader["y"]);
                                        //Console.WriteLine("width" + reader["width"]);
                                        //Console.WriteLine("height" + reader["height"]);
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            case XmlNodeType.Text:

                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }

                }

            }
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the elements is wrong. You've defined the order as `line-text`, `box-text` and `relative-text` and not as in your example `line-text`, `relative-text`, `box-text`

So either change your template xml to:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>  
<template-content output-directory='D:\\output'>
    <line-text name='a' />
    <box-text name='c' x='1' y='2' width='2' height='2' />
    <relative-text name='b' flow='above' amount='1'/>
</template-content>
```

Or use `<xs:all />` instead of `<xs:sequence />` in your schema

```
<xs:all>
    <xs:element name="line-text" type="LineText" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="box-text" type="BoxText"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
    <xs:element name="relative-text" type="RelativeText" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:all>
```

**Edit**
I think I've misread your schema. With `<xs:all />` It would allow one of each element in arbitrary order. But from your schema it looks like you want any number of the elements in arbitrary order. For this you will have to use `<xs:choice maxOccurs="unbound" />`.

```
<xs:choice maxOccurs="unbound">
    <xs:element name="line-text" type="LineText" />
    <xs:element name="box-text" type="BoxText" />
    <xs:element name="relative-text" type="RelativeText" />
</xs:choice>
```

Comment: I don t to be bound to sequencing them, but if I write xs:all I get this: Unhandled Exception: System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaException: The {max occurs} of all the
particles in the {particles} of an all group must be 0 or 1.